# camel jetty continuation exception

Tags: java, jetty, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm triggering an inout exchange via activemq to a route which performs a slow SQL query. the jetty servlet is timing out:

WARN org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet - Continuation expired of exchangeId: ID-wsintc01-40254-1395419854072-0-3

I've tried all the variations I can think of for useContinuation and continuationTimout but i still get the 503 error.

When the query completes I then get:

QueueReplyManager[x]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet - Cannot resume expired continuation of exchangeId: ID-wsintc01-40254-1395419854072-0-3

This is the route in the integration route set:

```
<route>
  <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{jetty.port}}/fetch_schedules?continuationTimeout={{jetty.continuationTimeout}}"/>
  <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
  <to uri="activemq:scheduler:getTVA?disableTimeToLive=true&amp;requestTimeout={{scheduler.timeout}}&amp;replyTo={{me.replyQueue}}&amp;replyToType=Exclusive"/>
  <to uri="velocity:view.vm"/>
  <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <constant>text/html;</constant>
  </setHeader>
</route>
```

The route in the scheduler just calls a java bean which does multiple sql queries of the database and builds an XML document.

Comment: What's your camel route look like ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the activemq response takes longer than the continuationTimeout on the jetty route, jetty will close the connection and return a 503.

I suggest setting requestTimeout option on the activemq and the continuationTimeout on the jetty route to the same value or make the continuationTimeout longer or infinite (0).